# call a classic asp page from a console application

Tags: web-services, asp-classic, httpwebrequest

I need to call my .NET (C#) web service from a classic asp page. I want to test it by creating a console application that calls the asp page.
This is my asp page:

```
Dim strUserID
Dim strUserName
Dim strUserEmail

strUserID = Request.Form("UserID")
strUserName = Request.Form("UserName")
strUserEmail = Request.Form("UserEMail")

SET objSoapClient = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient")
objSoapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True

Call objSoapClient.mssoapinit("http://localhost:/MyWebService/Service1/" & _
                                     "MyWebService.asmx?WSDL", "MyWebService")

strReturnValue = objSoapClient.SendData(strUserID, strUserName, strUserEmail)
response.Write("Returned from service with return value: " & strReturnValue)
```

Now my console application has to call the .asp page.
How do I construct the URL?
If the asp page is located in this folder:  C:\Folder1\OldPage.asp, how do I construct the URL?

This is what I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();      
    Uri aspPagingServiceUri = new Uri("http://localhost/Folder1/OldPage.asp?UserID=g39s24&UserName=Gloria Test$UserEmail=gtest@hvhs.org");
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(aspPagingServiceUri);       
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
    string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(strResponse);

    reader.Close();
}
```

I get the error: 'The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. ' when it gets to the `GetResponse` function.

I believe my problem is with the creation of the URL.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I have trying to connect to the ASP file that on the web server.  I am getting a (500) error:  "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
The file is folder:  C:\inetpub/wwwroot/Apps/Services/ServiceNew.asp
This is my console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri aspPagingServiceUri = new Uri("http://myserverName/Apps/Services/ServiceNew.asp?UserID=g39r345&UserName=John Smith&UserEmail=jsmith@mydomain.com&Subject=Test&MSG=Testing&ContactList=Sam Smith;");
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(aspPagingServiceUri);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
        string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(strResponse);

        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Web Exception: " + wex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("General Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The error is occurring `var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();`

Am I creating the URL correctly?
I am just following the file path.

Comment: I am calling a classic ASP file to run.  I don't know if it has special libraries, components to add.

Comment: Apologies - I'll remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not execute ASP code directly. What you need is to setup a web server that can execute classic ASP, i.e. Internet Information Services (IIS) on your machine, on another computer in a local network or externally.

IIS is part of some Windows distributions, you may just have to activate it. Make sure to install the classic ASP module, as this is not installed by default nowadays.

A warning: classic ASP often depends on additional COM components. So you may have to install more to get your code working.

Comment: Thanks.  I pulled this ASP file off of a web server in which one of our applications is calling.  So, theoretically, I can put this file on that web server and call it using my console application.

Comment: Yes, the ASP file can only run on a web server. You can put the URL together and test in your browser and use that URL in the console application. You can also just use `Invoke-WebRequest` (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) in a Powershell or `curl` on Linux/Mac if your console application is just to call a web service.

Comment: The console application is just a driver to simulate the application that will run the ASP file.  I have to change the ASP file to call a web service that I created using C# .NET 4.0 Framework.  I am just setting up the test environment to run the ASP file.

Comment: When I try connecting to the ASP file, I get the error:  The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
I will show my code above.

Comment: The good news is, your console Application works, error 500 is a server error, so you are already calling the right URL. The bad news is, the ASP code yields an error, you will have to debug this. Calling the URL in your browser might give you more details. Otherwise, getting more details on ASP errors is covered in a lot of questions on SO already.

Comment: Thanks!  I will take it from here.  You have been a great help.